# Cannot read Node-RED on IBM Cloud logs

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I have a simple Node-RED runtime and want to analyse the logs as the debug messages are too big. However, on the log page I can not scroll, use filters, magnifying class etc.. I only see the spinning wheel. Tested several browsers.

Comment: I always use the cli.  `bx cf logs <app name>` to tail.  Add `--recent` to dump the whole log.

Comment: ok, sure thing, thank you!